# I received better job offer, should I move on?

Tags: job-offer, first-job

I recently accepted a job offer in software engineering and my salary is reasonable. I have been working for five weeks, until I was offered a job from a top-tier company with 50% higher salary this week. I had applied and interviewed for these jobs at the same time, but the top-tier company took longer to process my application, or they have had too many applicants.

Although the new job offer is paying 50% higher than what I am receiving at the moment, I am still not sure if I should ask for an excuse and resign from my current job to move on to the new job.

I have two concerns about doing this: (1) The current company has spent some money on my laptop and work gear, and I feel bad if I just leave within a short period of time. (2) The current company has really nice people with whom I have really enjoyed working. I feel bad for moving to a new environment due to a traumatic experience in my first job.

I am not sure if my lack of tendency for leaving my current company is logical, or it stems from my "safe workplace anxiety" in my first experience. That is why I decided to post this question here and ask for opinions from people who are in later stages of their career. Is it a good idea to move on or it is too risky?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Having another work environment that has bad colleagues.

Comment: The grass is always greener on the other side of the street. Are you contented and happy where you are?

Comment: @EdHeal Yes, my current job is really good in terms of the culture and environment. However, the pay of the new job is 50% better.

Answer (score 7):

tl-dr answer: We can't tell you what is *best for you*.

Assessing any job involves a balance of considerations - salary being one, but also working conditions, perks, commute, company reputation, colleagues, role, topic of work, sphere of influence (you may feel like a very small cog in a big machine at a large top-tier company, for example). Everyone has a different way of weighing these up.

Having said that, you're five weeks into a job. Nothing wrong with that, but you need to be *confident* you are going to be measurably happier by moving. If you aren't, and leave the next company quickly, you will be seen as a job-hopper. You don't sound confident. Beware the trap of considering only headline salary.

Comment: This is exactly my problem. I have no idea what is it like working in there. Are colleagues nice or it is going to be like my first job. The main reason I am not so confident in the role is that I think the same thing is going to happen.

P.S. Some of the things like working conditions, work/life balance, commute are the same in both companies.